# Analyzing Optimal Search Strategies for Rewards in a Game with Unbalanced Odds

Tags: expected-value, uncertainty, game-theory

I have received an invitation to participate in a game show where the amount I could potentially win depends on how well I perform. The game requires me to find diamonds hidden in 30 vases that are spread across two rooms, each with 15 vases.

One vase in Room A contains a diamond worth one unit, and another vase in Room B also has a diamond of the same value. Although I must start my search in Room A, I have the option to stop searching at any point and proceed to Room B. However, once I enter Room B, I am not permitted to go back to Room A.

If I find both diamonds, I will be rewarded with a third diamond that is worth five times the value of a standard diamond.

To maximize my potential winnings, what is the best strategy to follow? Furthermore, how could I generalize this problem to include diamonds with a greater difference in value?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Based on the problem description, I would search all the vases in room A until I find the diamond, then move to room B and do the same.  Are you leaving something important out?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe I'm not leaving anything behind, and I have also come to this solution myself (searching until exhaustion). I was just wondering if there's a better strategy I'm missing. This is not homework; it's a personal project. My main issue is the best way to maximize my chance of winning the 5x diamond.

Comment: The trouble is there's no cost to exhaustive search, which implies that must be the best strategy, as it's guaranteed to achieve the maximum reward.  There may be other strategies that do so (not in this case) but w/o a search cost they are no better than exhaustive search.

Comment: I'm sorry; I completely missed a crucial detail. I'm only allowed to search in 15 vases in total

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  You should add that into the body of the original post!

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a strategy that stays in room $A$ until a diamond is found, even if it means all 15 trials are needed, and only switches to room $B$ if a diamond is found and we haven't used up all 15 trials.

We are assured of finding the diamond in room $A$, so the expected value of this strategy ($V_1$) is at least equal to $1$.  In fact, if we find the diamond before the $15^{th}$ trial, there is a nonzero probability that we will also find the diamond in room $B$ in the remaining trials; therefore, $V_1 > 1$. (We don't need to calculate it exactly for what follows, easy though that may be.)

Now let's compare this to a strategy that switches to room $B$ after $k \geq 0$ failures.  (Obviously we will always switch to room $B$ after a success.)  The expected value $V_2(k)$ of switching is just the probability of finding the diamond in room $B$:

$$V_2(k) = {15-k\over 15} = 1 - {k\over 15} \leq 1 < V_1$$

Therefore, it never pays to switch before finding the diamond.

To generalize this, let's fix the value of the diamond in room $A$ at $1$ with no loss of generality.  We set the value of the diamond in room $B$ equal to $v_B$ and the value of the "extra" diamond at $v_E$.

The expected value of strategy $1$ is equal to the value of the diamond in room $A$ ($1$) plus the probability of finding the diamond in room $B$ times the value of doing so given that we found the diamond in room $A$.  Since, on average, we will require $15/2 = 7.5$ trials to find the diamond in room $A$, we will have, on average, $7.5$ trials in room $B$, which gives us a $50\%$ chance of finding the diamond:

$$V_1 = 1 + 0.5(v_B + v_E)$$

The value of switching after $k$ failures is:

$$V_2(k) = \left(1 - {k \over 15}\right)v_B$$

Obviously this will be maximized at $k=0$, with associated value $v_B$.  Therefore, we switch immediately if and only if:

$$v_B > 1 + 0.5(v_B + v_E)$$

A little algebra leads to a simpler version of this condition:

$$v_B > 2 + v_E$$